# Is it possible to do row reference in ADF data mapping flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-build-task, data-mapping

We received a dataset with data broken out in tranches by category, and would like to put the tranche breaker "Department" into its own column, so the output should be "department", "employee code", "salary" and remove the extra rows at the bottom. Is there anyway to achieve this?
[image]

Sample output

[image]

Comment: can you share sample Output?

Comment: @PratikLad sure, added sample output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a new column called department and fill the data in the column, you can follow the below steps.

1. `source transformation` is taken for input data.

[image]

2. `derive transformation` is taken to add a new column called "Department".  The expression for this column is given as
   `iif(isNull(toInteger(EmployeeCode)),EmployeeCode,toString(null()))`. Another column named `dummy` is added and value is given as `1`.

[image]

3. `Surrogate Key transformation` is added to generate a surrogate key for each row in the data flow.

[image]

[image]

4. `window tansformation` is taken to  fill the missing values in the "Department" column using the `last` function.

[image: gif1]

5. `filter transformation` is taken to filter out the rows where the "Salary" column is null. and then `select transformation` is taken to select the "EmployeeCode", "Salary", and "Department" columns.

[image]

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#fill-down